# How to implement a custom 'fmt::Debug' trait?

Tags: rust

I presume you do something like this:

```
extern crate uuid;

use uuid::Uuid;
use std::fmt::Formatter;
use std::fmt::Debug;

#[derive(Debug)]
struct BlahLF {
    id: Uuid,
}

impl BlahLF {
    fn new() -> BlahLF {
        return BlahLF { id: Uuid::new_v4() };
    }
}

impl Debug for BlahLF {
    fn fmt(&self, &mut f: Formatter) -> Result {
        write!(f.buf, "Hi: {}", self.id);
    }
}
```

...but attempting to implement this trait generates:

```
error[E0243]: wrong number of type arguments
  --> src/main.rs:19:41
   |
19 |     fn fmt(&self, &mut f: Formatter) -> Result {
   |                                         ^^^^^^ expected 2 type arguments, found 0
```

However, that seems to be how other implementations do it. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Would be useful to also paste the sample main/ rust playground link.

Answer (score 82):

According to the example from the [`std::fmt` docs](http://static.rust-lang.org/doc/master/std/fmt/index.html):

```
extern crate uuid;

use uuid::Uuid;
use std::fmt;

struct BlahLF {
    id: Uuid,
}

impl fmt::Debug for BlahLF {
    fn fmt(&self, f: &mut fmt::Formatter) -> fmt::Result {
        write!(f, "Hi: {}", self.id)
    }
}
```

The part to emphasize is the `fmt::` in `fmt::Result`. Without that you're referring to the plain [`Result`](http://static.rust-lang.org/doc/master/std/result/enum.Result.html) type. The plain `Result` type *does* have two generic type parameters, `fmt::Result` has none.

Comment: `std::fmt` docs no longer provide an example for implementing `fmt::Debug` by hand.

Comment: I remain amazed that this example is not on this page and I keep having to google this answer. https://doc.rust-lang.org/stable/core/fmt/trait.Debug.html

Comment: @Alper apparently they read your comment because it's back on the page you linked too. Thank you!

Comment: I think I was the one who added it there!

Comment: Don't use `write!` for manual debug implementations. If you're implementing `Debug` manually then read *[this page](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/fmt/trait.Debug.html#examples)*, and use `debug_struct`.

Comment: The deleted answer from @Doug is the right answer and should be undeleted.

Answer (score 0):

As explained in the comments of **cnd**'s original answer, the modern way to do this is to use `debug_struct`. There's a helpful example in the [Rust docs for `debug_struct`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/fmt/struct.Formatter.html#method.debug_struct):

```rust
use std::fmt;
use std::net::Ipv4Addr;

struct Foo {
    bar: i32,
    baz: String,
    addr: Ipv4Addr,
}

impl fmt::Debug for Foo {
    fn fmt(&self, fmt: &mut fmt::Formatter<'_>) -> fmt::Result {
        fmt.debug_struct("Foo")
            .field("bar", &self.bar)
            .field("baz", &self.baz)
            .field("addr", &format_args!("{}", self.addr))
            .finish()
    }
}
```

This is much more ergonomic for real-world use, where your struct will probably have several fields that you're happy to use the default implementation for, and then one that needs special handling.