# How to implement the ToString trait to create a comma-delimited string without a trailing comma?

Tags: rust

I have this code:

```
struct A {
    names: Vec<String>,
}

impl ToString for A {
    fn to_string(&self) -> String {
        // code here
    }
}

fn main() {
    let a = A {
        names: vec!["Victor".to_string(), "Paul".to_string()],
    };
    println!("A struct contains: [{}].", a.to_string());
}
```

Expected output:

> A struct contains: [Victor, Paul].

What is the best way to implement this trait to achieve the goal? I have tried some weird 'for each' and other variants, but each one gives me a trailing comma like this:

> Victor, Paul,

Of course I can pop it off later, but I am interested in the language so I want to know the best practice of this. This is just an example of what I've tried, but it does not matter, I am asking how to do this most efficiently.

Answer (score 32, accepted):

According to [the `ToString` documentation](https://doc.rust-lang.org/stable/std/string/trait.ToString.html):

> This trait is automatically implemented for any type which implements the [`Display`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/stable/std/fmt/trait.Display.html) trait. As such, `ToString` shouldn't be implemented directly: `Display` should be implemented instead, and you get the `ToString` implementation for free.

You can implement `Display` like this:

```
use std::fmt;

impl fmt::Display for A {
    fn fmt(&self, fmt: &mut fmt::Formatter) -> fmt::Result {
        let mut str = "";
        for name in &self.names {
            fmt.write_str(str)?;
            fmt.write_str(name)?;
            str = ", ";
        }
        Ok(())
    }
}
```

And you don't need to call `to_string` (but you can):

```
fn main() {
    let a = A {
        names: vec!["Victor".to_string(), "Paul".to_string()],
    };
    println!("A struct contains: [{}].", a);
}
```

Note the purpose of the `Display`:

> `Display` is similar to [`Debug`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/stable/std/fmt/trait.Debug.html), but `Display` is for user-facing output, and so cannot be derived.

If your intent is debug, you can derive `Debug`:

```
#[derive(Debug)]
struct A {
    names: Vec<String>,
}

fn main() {
    let a = A { names: vec![
        "Victor".to_string(),
        "Paul".to_string(),
    ]};
    // {:?} is used for debug
    println!("{:?}", a);
}
```

Outputs:

```
A { names: ["Victor", "Paul"] }
```

The [`Formatter`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/stable/std/fmt/struct.Formatter.html) struct offers a rich collections of methods, so you can write your own `Debug` implementation:

```
impl fmt::Debug for A {
    fn fmt(&self, fmt: &mut fmt::Formatter) -> fmt::Result {
        fmt.debug_struct("A")
           .field("names", &self.names)
           .finish()
    }
}
```

Comment: Everything looks awesome but should I care for `fmt.write_str()` return value? The compiler complains that result must be used and gives a warning.

Comment: You are right. The call must be wrapped by [`try!`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/stable/std/macro.try!.html) macro. I updated the answer. Thanks.

Comment: What do you think of closing as a duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/q/22243527/155423 ?

Comment: @Shepmaster I think that this question is not duplicate. This question is about implementing `ToString` and although in the end it maybe means implementing `Display`, the concern is different  from implementing `Debug`.

Comment: May someone point to a resource which clarifies the underhood magic which automatically enables `ToString` for `Display` please? [Display](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/fmt/trait.Display.html) trait documentation itself doesn't mention about such "free" implementation, while [ToString](https://doc.rust-lang.org/stable/std/string/trait.ToString.html) does. It seems counterintuitive

Comment: @Cryptor I agree that it's not the clearest documentation, but here's a link to the blanket implementation of ToString for all types that implement Display.  https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/string/trait.ToString.html#impl-ToString-for-T