# Function pointer with a reference argument cannot derive Debug

Tags: rust

I have a enum where I want to generalize an function pointer. As soon as I add a reference inside the function pointer definition. it fails to compile because it cannot print it with `Debug`:

```
fn div1(t: i64, b: i64) -> i64 {
    t / b
}

fn div2(t: i64, b: &i64) -> i64 {
    t / b
}

#[derive(Debug)]
enum Enum {
    FnTest1(fn(i64, i64) -> i64),
    FnTest2(fn(i64, &i64) -> i64),
}

fn main() {
    println!("{:?}", Enum::FnTest1(div1));
    println!("{:?}", Enum::FnTest2(div2));
}
```

The error I get is this

```
error[E0277]: `for<'r> fn(i64, &'r i64) -> i64` doesn't implement `std::fmt::Debug`
  --> src/main.rs:12:13
   |
12 |     FnTest2(fn(i64, &i64) -> i64),
   |             ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ `for<'r> fn(i64, &'r i64) -> i64` cannot be formatted using `{:?}` because it doesn't implement `std::fmt::Debug`
   |
   = help: the trait `std::fmt::Debug` is not implemented for `for<'r> fn(i64, &'r i64) -> i64`
   = note: required because of the requirements on the impl of `std::fmt::Debug` for `&for<'r> fn(i64, &'r i64) -> i64`
   = note: required for the cast to the object type `dyn std::fmt::Debug`
```

It only shows an error for `FnTest2` which has a reference argument while `FnTest1` works fine.

Is this a bug in Rust or is there a solution or an alternative method to this issue?

I am running Rust nightly (rustup says: `rustc 1.30.0-nightly (ae7fe84e8 2018-09-26)`).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Is this a bug in Rust

No, but it is a limitation:

- [Cannot derive(Debug) for a struct with a function with a reference parameter (#45048)](https://github.com/rust-lang/rust/issues/45048)
- [#[derive] Debug, PartialEq, Hash, etc. for any function pointers, regardless of type signature (#54508)](https://github.com/rust-lang/rust/issues/54508)

> is there a solution or an alternative method

Yes, [you must implement `Debug` for the type `Enum` yourself](https://stackoverflow.com/q/22243527/155423).

Comment: Oh, that's unfortunate. Works for a few of my test cases but I also now get a stack overflow in one apparently but that's a seperate issue. Thanks!